# qml: how to reference an image path

Tags: image, path, qml

I'm working on a Main.qml file, which depends from a second qml file, located in a library path (such as /usr/lib/qt5/...).

My images are accessible from Main.qml using a reative path.
source: images/image.png

The second qml file, instead, doesn't knows the absolute location of Main.qml, so it canno't access my images.
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution.

In Main.qml, I can to define a variable such as:

property string imagePath: Qt.resolvedUrl("images/")

and I can pass it to the second qml.